# How to do a statistical test for numeric data that is discretised and broken down by groups

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance

**Background**
I have a situation where I have data on bank balances available with various respondents, and a flag for whether they completed a desired action (i.e., whether they purchased a loan or not).  The data on savings/money has been discretised, however.

**Problem**
A concern has been raised that the bank balances of respondents might not be the actual ones, but updated (updated bank balance = original balance + loaned amount).

*How to verify this?* I have tried formulating an approach below.

**Solution formulation**

Since I only have discretised data, I thought I could set up a statistical hypothesis test for proportions.
Hypothesis: If the proportion of success/loan purchasers increases drastically as we move up higher in account balance groups, it would indicate the balances are inclusive of loans.

[image]

As shown, there is an unexpected increase in success rate, and at this point, it seems no statistical test is needed?

**My questions:**

1. Is the aforesaid sufficient evidence? How can I make it more thorough (statistically), assuming I will not get the actual balances?
2. If I did get actual balances, how can I gather evidence to verify that there is/is not a group of people whose balances are inflated due to loan amount

I am *extremely interested* in understanding Stats. application to such problems, and understanding the Statistical theory, so I would be indebted to understand the wrongs of my way.

**Data**

```r
structure(list(finalClass = c("Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", 
"Success", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", 
"Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", 
"Success", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", 
"Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", 
"Success", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", 
"Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", 
"Reject/Cancel", "Reject/Cancel", "Success", "Reject/Cancel", 
"Reject/Cancel", "Success"), balance_new_bracket = c("01. <= 10k", 
"01. <= 10k", "02. 10k - 20k", "02. 10k - 20k", "03. 20k - 30k", 
"03. 20k - 30k", "04. 30k - 40k", "04. 30k - 40k", "05. 40k - 50k", 
"05. 40k - 50k", "06. 50k - 60k", "06. 50k - 60k", "07. 60k - 70k", 
"07. 60k - 70k", "08. 70k - 80k", "08. 70k - 80k", "09. 80k - 90k", 
"09. 80k - 90k", "10. 90k - 100k", "10. 90k - 100k", "11. 100k - 200k", 
"11. 100k - 200k", "12. 200k - 300k", "12. 200k - 300k", "13. 300k - 400k", 
"13. 300k - 400k", "14. 400k - 500k", "14. 400k - 500k", "15. 500k - 600k", 
"15. 500k - 600k", "16. 600k - 1M", "16. 600k - 1M", "17. 1M - 2M", 
"17. 1M - 2M", "18. 2M - 3M", "19. 3M - 6M", "19. 3M - 6M", "20. > 6M", 
"20. > 6M"), N = c(18232L, 5115L, 1697L, 819L, 364L, 761L, 476L, 
245L, 308L, 137L, 210L, 108L, 155L, 89L, 77L, 137L, 52L, 108L, 
103L, 39L, 569L, 260L, 233L, 182L, 1597L, 156L, 109L, 817L, 590L, 
116L, 817L, 100L, 51L, 62L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L), percent = c(0.780914036064591, 
0.219085963935409, 0.674483306836248, 0.325516693163752, 0.323555555555556, 
0.676444444444444, 0.660194174757282, 0.339805825242718, 0.692134831460674, 
0.307865168539326, 0.660377358490566, 0.339622641509434, 0.635245901639344, 
0.364754098360656, 0.35981308411215, 0.64018691588785, 0.325, 
0.675, 0.725352112676056, 0.274647887323944, 0.686369119420989, 
0.313630880579011, 0.56144578313253, 0.43855421686747, 0.911009697661152, 
0.0889903023388477, 0.117710583153348, 0.882289416846652, 0.835694050991501, 
0.164305949008499, 0.890948745910578, 0.109051254089422, 0.451327433628319, 
0.548672566371681, 1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.8, 0.2), tots = c(23347L, 
23347L, 2516L, 2516L, 1125L, 1125L, 721L, 721L, 445L, 445L, 318L, 
318L, 244L, 244L, 214L, 214L, 160L, 160L, 142L, 142L, 829L, 829L, 
415L, 415L, 1753L, 1753L, 926L, 926L, 706L, 706L, 917L, 917L, 
113L, 113L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), conf_low = c(0.775552136317493, 
0.213794081502295, 0.65578046562415, 0.307220804467065, 0.296264735635882, 
0.648227521218143, 0.624326658051425, 0.305255642604346, 0.646947176024304, 
0.265253980427813, 0.60544358384926, 0.287709357961987, 0.571443652323727, 
0.304282016481803, 0.295522603420615, 0.571952527712148, 0.25317409400087, 
0.596551368545636, 0.64420157566435, 0.203150823708409, 0.653560936603063, 
0.282154345692913, 0.51220524670192, 0.390195953557052, 0.896698056863425, 
0.076072772673856, 0.0976559949418072, 0.859767702403072, 0.80626156910148, 
0.137713232814479, 0.868959355941994, 0.0896127959455879, 0.357541357583628, 
0.452272456810347, 0.663732883120057, 0.00630946320970987, 0.194120449683243, 
0.283582063881911, 0.00505076337946806), conf_hi = c(0.786205918497705, 
0.224447863682507, 0.692779195532935, 0.34421953437585, 0.351772478781857, 
0.703735264364118, 0.694744357395654, 0.375673341948575, 0.734746019572187, 
0.353052823975696, 0.712290642038013, 0.39455641615074, 0.695717983518197, 
0.428556347676273, 0.428047472287852, 0.704477396579385, 0.403448631454364, 
0.74682590599913, 0.796849176291591, 0.35579842433565, 0.717845654307087, 
0.346439063396937, 0.609804046442948, 0.48779475329808, 0.923927227326144, 
0.103301943136575, 0.140232297596928, 0.902344005058193, 0.862286767185521, 
0.19373843089852, 0.910387204054412, 0.131040644058006, 0.547727543189653, 
0.642458642416372, 1, 0.805879550316757, 0.99369053679029, 0.994949236620532, 
0.716417936118089)), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = "data.frame")
```

PS. This is a cross-post from Twitter, where I tried having a discussion about this (and one of the gentlemen, Frank Harrell, advised on getting actual balances) but I realised it is a lengthy one.

Comment: Why would bank balances be exclusive of loans? What does that mean? Somebody fills in the form about their bank balance and subtracts the loan from it? (or maybe it means they have a loan, but also invested it again?) How do you see bank balance connected to loan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Q1**
Setting up notation: for a single account, let $X_1$ be the categorical random variable giving the true balance *not including* the loaned amount, and suppose this has a true unknown discrete distribution $F_{X_1}(x)$. Let $X_2$ be the categorical random variable giving the true balance *including* the loaned amount, and suppose this has a true unknown distribution $F_{X_2}(x)$. Let $Y$ be a binary random variable indicating loan success. You have some observed data $\{x_i, y_i\}_{i=1}^n$, and I understand you to be asking the question: "Do my $x_i$'s come from $F_{X_1}(x)$?". From a hypothesis testing perspective, your null distribution would be whatever your expected distribution of $X_1$ is, and you could conduct a $\chi^2$ test on your data, i.e. calculate the expected and the observed number of observations in each category, etc. Call this **Approach 1**. It's not obvious to me what your null distribution should be, but I would expect it to have one mode at the lowest category and to be highly right-skewed; the example I give below uses the geometric distribution. Your data have two modes (category 1 and category 13), and, as you suggest, a likely explanation for the second mode at category 13 is that your data actually include loan balances.

Below is an implementation of this approach which calculates the MLE of the parameter assuming that the counts of loan categories are distributed according to a geometric distribution and then uses that MLE to calculate the chi-square statistic and a corresponding p-value. It is tiny, i.e. $<10^{-16}$

```r
library(tidyverse)

# loan_data is the name of the data.frame created by the OP code
observed_n_per_cat <- 
  loan_data %>% 
  filter(finalClass == "Success") %>% 
  pull(tots)

geom_negloglikelihood = function(logit_prob, dat) {
  -sum(dgeom(seq_along(dat)-1, prob = plogis(logit_prob), log = T) * dat)
}

mle_prob = 
  plogis(optimize(f = geom_negloglikelihood, dat = observed_n_per_cat, lower = -10, upper = 10)$minimum)

expected_n_per_cat = 
  sum(observed_n_per_cat) * dgeom(seq_along(observed_n_per_cat)-1, prob = mle_prob)

chisq_statistic <- 
  sum((observed_n_per_cat - expected_n_per_cat)^2 / expected_n_per_cat)

pchisq(chisq_statistic, df = length(observed_n_per_cat) - 1, lower = F)
```

Your approach seems to be answering a slightly different question, namely "Do my $y_i$'s come from some distribution $F_{Y|X=x}(y)$?". You are suggesting to posit a null distribution such that $F_{Y|X=x}(y)$ doesn't increase too fast in $x$. Call this **Approach 2**

Approach 1 is, in my mind, a more direct approach to answer your main question, whereas Approach 2, by asking a question about the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$, is a somewhat roundabout way to infer about the distribution of your $x$. Moreover, as the previous responder Martin noted, you would probably always expect $F_{Y|X=x}(y)$ to increase somewhat with $x$, which makes it more difficult to specify how drastic of an increase in success rate is too drastic.

**For Q2** If you had the numeric balances, I would still probably suggest an approach similar to Approach 1 above: posit some now-continuous distribution $F_{X_1}(x)$ corresponding to the distribution of balances without loans, and test whether your now-continuous data arise from that distribution.

Comment: thank you _very_ much indeed for your help.
For the chi-squared test, AFAIK, is not the expected no. of observations estimated from the data (row total * col total), so that we are unable to postulate _our_ expected no. of observations?

Comment: Correct: in order to get an expected number of observations in each category, we would need to assume some posited family of distributions that is generating the data. I have modified my answer to include some code that assumes the data arise from a geometric distribution, which is one simple family that is (i) unimodal at the lowest category (ii) decreasing with category. As you can see, the p-value is very tiny, which rejects the hypothesis that your data arise from the geometric family of distributions

Comment: Hi @psboonstra! Hope you have been well. Could you explain why you are using `seq_along(dat)` for dgeom, instead of counts, as you do later for chisq test? And also then `plogis(logit_prob)`? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello. To you first question, it's easier to see by looking at the whole expression: `dgeom(seq_along(dat)-1, prob = plogis(logit_prob), log = T)` calculates the log-probabilities of 0, 1, 2, ... failures occurring before a success, given that the true probability is plogis(logit_prob). This becomes the log-likelihood contribution once we multiply this vector by the data and sum. `plogis()` is the standard logistic CDF, and I am using here as a function mapping from R -> (0,1) so that I can optimize over the whole real line instead of a compact interval. I thought this would be better behaved.

Answer (score 3):

If you would have some model for these type of data then you could test the model with a statistical test. But you do not seem to have a model, so the question is a bit difficult.

---

Anyway the plot shows a clear jump after 300k

(and you could probably make some non-parameteric test if you would have a null hypothesis that the density should be monotonically decreasing without bumps; but it would still be difficult to interpret the causes for that null hypothesis to be falsified)

[image: example]

The problem that your questions/effects are not really expressible in terms of a quantitative expression. And also, it is unclear what we are looking at.

What is that bump supposed to be? Does it mean that you attract more respondents that are wealthy and have loans? Or does it mean that clients with loans have more money on their bankaccount?

Anyway, I find it a strange bump and it does not make much sense to me. Even if you would ascribe that bump to loans included... I am not sure how to interpret that 'updated bank balance = old bank balance + loan'. I imagine that a person/household is not getting a loan to put it onto the bank balance, but instead will invest it (but maybe we are not talking about bank balance only, and instead something like *total* assets on a balance sheet?).

```
y1 <- data$N[dat$finalClass == 'Success']
y2 <- data$N[dat$finalClass != 'Success']
y1 <- c(y1[1:17],0,y1[18:19])
lab <- data$balance_new_bracket[dat$finalClass != 'Success']

range <- c(rep(10^4,10),rep(10^5,5),4*10^5,10^6,10^6,3*10^6,10*10^6)*sum(y1+y2)

plot((y1+y2)/range, log = "y", ylim = 10^c(-11,-4),xaxt = "n",
     xlab = "", ylab = "density")
points(y2/range, col = 2)
points(y1/range, col = 3)
axis(1, at=1:20, labels = lab, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.7)
legend(1,10^-11, c("total","success", "reject"), col = c(1,2,3), pch=1, yjust=0, cex = 0.7)
```

Comment: Thanks a *lot* for this! To address your questions:   
1. Hypothesis is that rich people do not need loans as much as the middle class (valid in the country I am working at), so we expect their 'participation' to be low  
2. Interpretation of 'updated bank balance = old bank balance + loan' is that once a bank offers a loan, it goes straight to the bank account; the bank balance data is assumed to be obtained right after the loan disbursement

Comment: What non-parametric test did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

For question 1., I think you either need to know *a lot* about the loan process or you are  doomed. Without much knowledge of the financial world, I would expect rich people (i.e. people with more money on their accounts) to be considered more credible to the banks and hence somewhat more likely to receive a loan. So you have two competing explanations for the increase in success rate (loan is included / rich people are more successful). To distinguish between those, you would need to somehow get an idea how much you would expect the success rate to vary with amount on the account even if you had the actual balances.

For question 2., you would want to compare if the two tables are "similar" in some sense. One way to do so would be to combine the two tables and add a new column `source` to distinguish whether this is the original data or the actual balances. Then you could do binomial regression, something like

```
glm(cbind(accepted, totalCustomers - accepted) ~ source * balance_bracket, family = "binomial", data = data_combined)
```

Comment: Thank you _very_ much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Too late, but thanks to other helpful answers that got me started in finding other similar approaches to tackle this problem.

Following is based on comments and answer from @psboonstra.

*FitDistrPlus approach*

```
# Original data loaded as loan_data

# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(fitdistrplus)

succ_count <- loan_data %>% 
  filter(finalClass == "Success") %>% 
  pull(N) %>% 
  data.frame(cat = 1:length(.), n = .) %>% 
  mutate(cat = cat - 1)

succ_n_per_cat <- rep(succ_count$cat, times = succ_count$n)
```

Using `fitdistrplus` helps a lot as it allows quick comparison of actual data with theoretical distribution, while also calculating the distribution params with highest likelihood.

Below, I will attempt `Geometric` and `Negative Binomial` distribution fitting.

*Geometric distribution*

```
geom_est <- fitdist(succ_n_per_cat, distr = "geom", method = "mle")

summary(geom_est)

#Fitting of the distribution ' geom ' by maximum likelihood 
#Parameters : 
#      estimate  Std. Error
#prob 0.1570848 0.001353016
#Loglikelihood:  -31446.77   AIC:  62895.53   BIC:  62902.87 

plot(geom_est)
```

[image]

This does not appear to be a very good fit, however. So let's try `Negative binomial distirbution` instead.

*Negative Binomial*

```
nbinom_est <- fitdist(succ_n_per_cat, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")
summary(nbinom_est)

#Fitting of the distribution ' nbinom ' by maximum likelihood 
#Parameters : 
#      estimate  Std. Error
#size 0.3172793 0.005458399
#mu   5.3666409 0.092002021
#Loglikelihood:  -29015.93   AIC:  58035.85   BIC:  58050.53 
#Correlation matrix:
#              size            mu
#size  1.0000000000 -0.0001151258
#mu   -0.0001151258  1.0000000000

plot(nbinom_est)
```

[image]

This appears to be a *slightly* better fit, and can possibly be used for a hypothesis test.